# From limit to almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, expected-value, convergence

Consider some real-valued random variables $\eta, Z_1,..., Z_J, \epsilon_1,..., \epsilon_J$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with $J\in \mathbb{N}$, and some functions $f,m,g,h$.

I have the following results
$$
\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty}\Big| J\mathbb{P}\Big(f(\eta)\geq m(Z_j,\epsilon_j) \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J| Z_1=z_1, Z_2=z_2, ..., Z_J=z_J\Big)- g(z_1,..., z_J)\Big|=0 \hspace{1cm}\forall (z_1,...,z_J)
$$
and
$$
g(z_1,Z_2, Z_3,..., Z_J) \rightarrow_{a.s.} h(z_1) \text{ }\text{ as $J\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

I want to show that

$$
J\mathbb{P}(f(\eta)\geq m(Z_j,\epsilon_j) \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J| Z_1=z_1)\rightarrow_{a.s.} h(z_1) \text{ } \text{ as $J\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

---

My attempt: i think I should start from noticing that by assumption
$$
\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty}\Big( J\mathbb{P}\Big(f(\eta)\geq m(Z_j,\epsilon_j) \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J| Z_1=z_1, Z_2=z_2, ..., Z_J=z_J\Big)- g(z_1,..., z_J)\Big)=0 \hspace{1cm}\forall (z_1,...,z_J)
$$
which implies
$$
J\mathbb{P}\Big(f(\eta)\geq m(Z_j,\epsilon_j) \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J\Big| Z_1=z_1, Z_2=z_2, ..., Z_J=z_J\Big)- g(z_1,..., z_J)\rightarrow_{a.s.} 0  \text{ } \text{ as $J\rightarrow \infty$} \hspace{1cm}\forall (z_1,...,z_J)
$$

Then the hint of the exercise is to use the triangle inequality but I have no idea on how to use it here.